# How to check if a user has a certain permission in a server?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I am making a delete messages command for my discord bot, and I want to make sure the user needs the 'Manage Server' permission in order to delete messages. On my main account, where I own the server, I am able to use the command, but on a test account I created, nothing happens and I get an error in the terminal: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: RangeError [BITFIELD_INVALID]: Invalid bitfield flag or number.

````
module.exports = {
    name: 'clear',
    description: 'clears messages',
    async execute(message, args){
        if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_SERVER')){
            if (!args[0]){
            message.reply('Please enter a valid amount of messages');
            }
        
            if (isNaN(args[0])){
            message.reply('Please enter a valid amount of messages');
            }
        
            if (args[0] > 100){
            message.reply('Please do not clear over 100 messages at once');
            }

            if (args[0] < 1){
            message.reply('Please enter a valid amount of messages');
            }

            await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then (messages => {
                message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
            });
        }else{
            message.channel.reply("You don't have the required roles to use the command.");
        }



    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had two very simple mistakes in your Code:

- You have used `MANAGE_SERVER`, which is not a property.
- You have used `message.channel.reply`, which is not a function.

Here is your fixed code:

```js
if (message.member.hasPermission('MANAGE_MESSAGES')){
        if (!args[0]){
        message.reply('Please enter a valid amount of messages');
        }
    
        if (isNaN(args[0])){
        message.reply('Please enter a valid amount of messages');
        }
    
        if (args[0] > 100){
        message.reply('Please do not clear over 100 messages at once');
        }

        if (args[0] < 1){
        message.reply('Please enter a valid amount of messages');
        }

        await message.channel.messages.fetch({limit: args[0]}).then (messages => {
            message.channel.bulkDelete(messages);
        });
    }else{
        message.reply("You don't have the required roles to use the command.");
    }
```

I used `MANAGE_MESSAGES`, but you can use whatever you want to use, but it has to be one of [these](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Permissions?scrollTo=s-FLAGS) properties. Your second error is simply fixed by just using: `message.reply`.